# Wordpress localhost OSX installation: Error establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, macos, nginx

I have a problem with Wordpress config on my localhost nginx.

On wp-admin configuration i receive `Error establishing a database connection`.

When I create wp-config manually, in mysql logs I have only `Aborted connection 12 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'dimmi' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)`

This is my debug log:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Users/patryk/Public/dimmi/dimmi_wordpress2/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1488

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /Users/patryk/Public/dimmi/dimmi_wordpress2/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1518

Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in /Users/patryk/Public/dimmi/dimmi_wordpress2/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1518`
```

Command line login and simple PHP script work perfectly, file permissions are 777.

I have OSX El Captain, mysql installed using homebrew. I ran out of ideas :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in connection between php and mysql.pls check following;

1.Check user name , password  is correct 
2.check the user 'dimmi' have permission for host 'localhost'  
3.is mysql running ? (since you can login from terminal,mysql is running  )
4.try to telnet localhost 3306
(this will return 
"Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]' " if mysql is running on your machine in 3306)